# Logging with slf4j, and 'logback', but not creating specified log file which is in configuration. (using maven, jetty)

Tags: maven, jetty, slf4j, logback

As specified in title I'm using Maven, and Jetty. For logging using SLF4J and Logback. I have 'logback.xml' at 'src/main/resources'.

```
    <configuration>
        <appender name="STDOUT"
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %class - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <appender name="FILE"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %class - %msg%n</pattern>
            </layout>
            <File>myLog.log</File>
        </appender>

        <logger name="org.mortbay">
            <level value="debug" />
        </logger>

        <root>
            <level value="error" />
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
</configuration>
```

But my problem is its not creating the file 'myLog.log' if I run/debug the project. What's the solution to get the log file.

Is there any way to get the log file only with SLF4J?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `<file>` instead of `<File>`?

Comment: @Raghuram, tried using <file> too, but no use.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry! I misunderstood the usage of 'Logback'. I got solution from http://www.mail-archive.com/user@slf4j.org/msg00661.html

i.e.

> It appears that you have misunderstood
>   the purpose of SLF4J. If you place
>   slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar then slf4j-api
>   will bind with java.util.logging.
>   Logback will not be used. Only if you
>   place logback-core.jar and
>   logback-classic.jar on your class path
>   (but not slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar) will
>   SLF4J API bind with logback. SLF4J
>   binds with one and only one underlying
>   logging API (per JVM launch).
>
> HTH,

Thanks to Ceki Gulcu. Now I can able to get logs in my file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JBoss 5.1 and you are having the same problem[logback not writing to file] then add the following in jboss-web.xml.

```
<class-loading>
    <loader-repository>
        com.hp:classloader=logback-slf4j
        <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>
</class-loading>
```

This should solve your problem.